# Key chords via xmodmap in 20.04

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout, xmodmap, remapping, chorded-keyboard

On macos I use a fabulous tool, [Karabiner Elements](https://karabiner-elements.pqrs.org/), to obtain the ability to use the `return` key as a control modifier key when typed with another key. Same for the `caps lock` key.

Now that I am moving most of my MacBook Pro laptops to Ubuntu, I am missing this feature dearly. Having symmetric control keys via this chording technique for the Apple keyboards has held off RSI nicely.

So my question: is xmodmap up to this kind of behavior? In a quick search, I did not see any promising results but thought I would ask here before drilling into the xmodmap docs.

Comment: Att least, you can have the CapsLock key act as a Ctrl or Super key. Your question looks like an XY problem. Real problem: use CapsLock/Enter as modifier keys, Y problem: I cannot do that with xmodmap.

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu, swap `Caps <> Ctrl` is built-in function of Gnome-Tweaks and `gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.input-sources xkb-options "['ctrl:swapcaps']"` this would do much faster. Xmodemap related questions are so many on this forum. I promise you can do it (if your mac is not broken.).